# How do I get Identity UserManager in .NET 6.0

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

The new .NET 6 Blazor templates have done away with `Startup.cs` and condensed everything into a much flatter structure.

I've previously used the `Startup.cs`'s `Configure` method to inject the `UserManager` and seed an admin user.

How can I do the same in the new structure?

I've not found a way to get the `UserManager` from anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following changes in `Program.cs` allow the DBInitializer to be called as before:

```
var scopeFactory = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
    ApplicationDbInitializer.Seed(userManager, roleManager);
}
```

Initializer for reference:

```
public static class ApplicationDbInitializer
{
    public static void Seed(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        bool adminRoleReady = false;
        bool adminUserReady = false;

        if (roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin").Result == null)
        {
            var role = new IdentityRole()
            {
                Name = "Admin",
            };

            var res = roleManager.CreateAsync(role).Result;

            adminRoleReady = res.Succeeded;
        }

        // ... more ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it using UserManager in .NET 6.0 & 7.0

In your `program.cs`

```cs
var scopeFactory = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();

// .. You can do migration here.

await DbSeeder.SeedUsers(userManager, roleManager);
```

The DbSeeder:

```cs
public static class DbSeeder
{
   public static async void SeedUsers(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> rolemanger){
     string[] roles = { "Admin", "User", "Guest", "SuperAdmin" };
     
     foreach (var role in roles)
     {
         var roleExist = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role);
         if (!roleExist)
         {
             await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole() { Name = role });
         }
     }
     
     // This will hold the User, Password & Role
     List<(ApplicationUser, string, string)> usersToCreate = new();

     var appUser = new ApplicationUser
     {
         UserName = "user@localhost",
         Email = "user@localhost",
         EmailConfirmed = true
     };
     
     usersToCreate.Add((appUser, "User$14123!", "User"));

     // You can add more users ...

     foreach (var item in usersToCreate)
     {
         var newUser = item.Item1;
         var userName = newUser.UserName;
         var password = item.Item2;
         var role = item.Item3;

         var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
         if (user == null)
         {
             var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, password);
             if (result.Succeeded)
             {
                 await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newUser, role);
             }
         }
     }     
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

create your project with asp.net core 3.1 then convert it to 6.0